# FOSUserBundle - Update email address and email canonical not working

Tags: php, api, symfony4, fosuserbundle, api-platform.com

After creating a user I want to make functionality to update email/ canonical email of the other accounts. I'm trying to update using:

```
$user = $this->fosUserManager->findUserBy(["id" => $id]);

$user->setEmail($content->email);
$this->fosUserManager->updateUser($user);
```

But this is not updating correctly. Is there any other way this can be done. Preferably by using the api platform itself.

Thanks and Regards :)

Comment: Why would you want to update email/ canonical information of "other" accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom data persister](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/#creating-a-custom-data-persister).